# Not trying to get random numbers for the values in my array

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

I am new  to programming in C++. I just would like to know why this code works, giving me actual numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 

    const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;
    int inc = 0;
    int arrayy[ARRAYSIZE];

    while (inc < ARRAYSIZE) {

        arrayy[inc]=inc;
        std::cout << arrayy[inc]<< endl;
        inc++;  
    }
}
```

But this code gives me random numbers for the values in my array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 

    const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;
    int inc = 0;
    int arrayy[ARRAYSIZE];

    while (inc < ARRAYSIZE) {

        arrayy[inc]=inc;
        inc++;
        std::cout << arrayy[inc]<< endl;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second case you're not printing the value you put into the array, you're printing the value in the next slot in the array, which may be anything.

Answer (score 3):

In the second one, you're setting a value to 0, then incrementing `inc`, so the value you print out is the one just *after* what you just set to 0. Since it hasn't been initialized (yet), it produces arbitrary ("random") values.

It also prints out the value one past the end of the array, giving undefined behavior when it does so.

Answer (score 1):

Values in the array are not initialized to any particular value, unless you specifically initialize them. In particular, all the values in `arrayy` will be "random" until you set them. In your first snippet, you set `arrayy[inc]`, and then print it; this works as you expect. In your second snippet, you set `arrayy[inc]`, and then print `arrayy[inc + 1]` (since you have already incremented `inc` at this point). But you haven't yet set `arrayy[inc + 1]` to anything, so the value printed is "random".